# PNG Name Displayed at Bottom

Tags: graphics, png

I am creating a document with an inserted PNG file, and I'm trying to create it where the name of the file is not located in the bottom left hand corner of it.

Here is part of the source code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\scalebox{0.5}[0.5]{\includegraphics*{C:/Users/PcOwmer/Pictures/OneFourthRSquaredSinFourTheta.png}}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't replicate this on my machine (though I'm using mac instead of windows) could you show us what output you're getting?  It also might help to put the file in the same location as your `tex` file and just use `\scalebox{0.5}[0.5]{\includegraphics*{OneFourthRSquaredSinFourTheta.png}}` instead of the full path.

Comment: What you said fixed my problem.

Comment: Cool! I would've made it an answer but I couldn't be 100% sure it was the solution because I couldn't replicate the error.

Comment: does your real path have spaces in filenames?